# Kendo PanelBar and nested floating divs (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-listview, kendo-panelbar

I am trying to insert a kendo listview in each of the panels but it seems to mess up because my listview  items have css float:left

I have simplified the problem to the following.. which does not show any items in the panelbar because the div has floating style

```
 @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
    .Name("panelbar")
    .ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Multiple)

    .Items(panelbar =>
    {
        panelbar.Add().Text("Images")
            .Expanded(true)

            .Content(@<text>
                <div style="float:left;">one</div>
                <div style="float:left;">two</div>

            </text>);
        panelbar.Add().Text("Movies")
                   .Expanded(true)
                   .Content(@<div>movies</div>);
        panelbar.Add().Text("Images")
                    .Expanded(true)
                    .Content(@<div>flash</div>);

    })
```

)

This is a very simplified version of what am trying to do which does not next a listview.
Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about the 2 divs you have defined there being floated left or the container?

Comment: the 2 divs i have in the example exhibit the same problem as when nesting a listview so i assumed it was because the items of the listview was producing left floating divs. so I tried a simple example like above and same problem occured.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or something to show what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

(Old question, but just to help the next person searching for this).

Add this to the bottom of your Content block containing the floated divs.

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```